# How to compile a Python script into a Unix executable and make it unreadable?

Tags: python, python-3.x, gcc, compilation

I know I can make a Python script a unix executable by using `#!/usr/bin/env python`, but if I open the executable with any text editor, the code can be seen by everyone.

I want to **compile** a python script into a real unix executable, that means that it is compiled to Assembly and nobody can read its code, and decompiling is really hard in Assembly.

I have seen Cython, which compiles Python code to C code, but it makes a .so (shared object) file, and cannot be executed, only imported.

This could also be done if there was a tool that really generates C/C++ code, not a .so, so then, using any compiler such as **gcc**, compile the *.c* or *.cpp* file. If this existed, it could also replace any other python compiler such as `py2app`, `py2exe` or any like that.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Is [packaging](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setuptools.html) and distributing as a [compiled wheel](https://packaging.python.org/guides/distributing-packages-using-setuptools/#wheels) an option for you? You can include [entry points](https://packaging.python.org/specifications/entry-points/) in the package which serve as `bin` files.

Comment: In any case you should be more clear about your intentions. If for example you have administrative rights on the system where the script runs you could simply remove read permission via `chmod og-r` and transfer the ownership to a specific user which then runs the script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [PyInstaller](http://www.pyinstaller.org/) or [py2exe](http://www.py2exe.org/).

Read:
https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/usage.html